# What audio drivers do I have to install?

Tags: drivers, sound

I'm using ubuntu 12.10. The problem is, when playing music through speakers, some zig zig sound is coming and the sound is not clear. What drivers do I have to install to make speakers sound clear?

Comment: Have you tried some testing by listening through headphone instead of speakers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install alsa drivers package, though not necessary because in most of the systems things work but in  case you are facing problems you should try alsa drivers for sound